# Conditional Application of Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $X,Y,Z$ be three positive random variables.
I want to find the following limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} E \left[ \frac{Y}{(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Z}  \right].
\end{align}

I was wondering if I there is an issue if I apply montone convergence theorem together with conditioning as follows:

\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} E \left[ \frac{Y}{(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Z}  \right]=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} E \left[ \frac{Y}{(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Z}  
 \Big| X \ge Z\right] P[X \ge Z] + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} E \left[ \frac{Y}{(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Z}  
 \Big| X < Z\right] P[X < Z].
\end{align}

Under the condition $X \ge Z$  we have that
\begin{align}
W_\epsilon=\frac{Y}{(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Z},
\end{align}
is monotone increasing and   under condition that $X \le Z$ we have that $W_\epsilon$ is motone decreasing.

So using monotone convergence theorem on both of these conditional expectations  we have that the limit is
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} E \left[ \frac{Y}{(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Z}  \right]=E \left[ \frac{Y}{X} \right].
\end{align}

Is this a correct proof? Did I miss anything?

Comment: What is your definition of conditional expectation? Because in my book, a conditional expectation is a random variable, in which case you wouldn't be able to apply monotone convergence directly.

Comment: @user159517  well here $\{X \ge Z\}$ is an event. So, $E[ W_\epsilon|  \{X \ge Z\}]=  \frac{E[ W_\epsilon 1_{\{X \ge Z\}}]}{P[\{X \ge Z\}]}$ where $1_{ \{\cdot \}}$ is an idicator function.

Comment: Why bother with the conditioning? Why not just write $E[W_\epsilon]=E[W_\epsilon\mathbf1_{\{X\ge Z\}}]+E[W_\epsilon\mathbf1_{\{X<Z\}}]$ and apply monotone convergence to each summand?

Comment: @Jason. Sure.  That is equivalent. I just needed a validation from someone that this is correct? Are there any issues with this? Do we need to assume anything more about $X,Y,Z$ other than positivity?

Comment: Yes, there are issues with the proof if you do not know that $E(\frac Y X) < \infty$. Monotone Convergence Theorem is not valid in general for decreasing sequences.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  Ok. Thanks. So, the assumption $E[ \frac{Y}{X} ]. Great

Answer (score 1):

The result is true as stated, but requires a more elaborate proof.
Lemma If $\{f_n\}$ is decreasing sequence of measurable functions with a.e. limit f and if at least one $f_n$ is integrable then $\int f_n d\mu \to \int f d\mu$. This follows by applying monotone convergence theorem to $\{f_1-f_n\}$. The argument of the OP along with this lemma gives the result easily when $E\frac Y X <\infty$. To prove the result when $E\frac Y X = \infty$ fix a positive integer N and let $Y_1=Y$ when $Y \leq NX$ and 0 otherwise. Note that $0 \leq Y_1 \leq Y$. Hence $E \frac Y {(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Y}$ $\geq E \frac {Y_1} {(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Y_1}$. ( This requires a little argument, but it is easy). Noting that $E\frac {Y_1} X <\infty$ we can apply the previous result to get $liminf E \frac Y {(1-\epsilon)X+\epsilon Y} \geq E\frac {Y_1} X$. Finally $E\frac {Y_1} X \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$. The rest is clear.

Comment: Let me also a counter example to show that Monotone Convergence Theorem fails for decreasing sequences. Consider $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure $m$ and let $f_n (x)=\frac 1 x$ if $0<x<\frac 1 n$ and 0 otherwise. We get a decreasing sequence of non-negative measurable functions converging pointwise to 0. However $\infty =\int f_n $ does not converge to $\int 0$.